# Python - Use certain position in list as a condition to trigger something else

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to think of a way to use a certain index of a list as a condition to trigger something else in python.

For example:

```
for val in mylist:
   do something with val (the actual list entry)
   if len(mylist)>= 4 and val has position 2 or bigger in mylist:
       do something else
```

It's important that the if loop remains valid from position 2 until the end of mylist.

what would be a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Something like this ? `mylist.index(val) >= 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, val in enumerate(my_list):
    do_something # will do this always
    if i >= 2:
        do_also_something_else # will be executed only when index is 2 or greater
```

Comment: that's great and simple! However, I need `val` as the actual value in the list for `do something`

Comment: @Shaun the above code will make sure `val` is the actual list value

Comment: @RobinZigmond ah I see! in `do_something_else` how can I use the values starting from position 2 upwards? `my_list[i]`?

Comment: @Shaun - the `if (i >= 2)` will ensure that automatically. Perhaps you should look up the documentation for `enumerate` so you understand this better: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate